# using a tileset with canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Yeah so I'm lost from the get-go. Alright let's say I have a big image with every tile for a 2D top-down RPG game. They're all the same width and everything. What I don't know is how would I save every individual tile from that image to their own image data for use on the canvas? Basically I want to take a big image with all my tiles, choose squares throughout it to make images out of the tiles, and store each image as a variable in an array. So, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canvas drawImage method to draw each of your tiles to a new canvas.

```
// assume your big source canvas is called tileSource
var tileWidth = 64;
var tileHeight = 64;
var tileCols = Math.round(tileSource.width/tileWidth);
var tileRows = Math.rounc(tileSource.height/tileHeight);

// array to store canvas elements
var myTiles = [];

// loop through for each tile in the source
for (var i=0; i<tileRows; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<tileColumns; j++) {
        // This is using jQuery to create the canvas element
        // .get(0) gets the actual canvas element from the jQuery object
        var tile = $('<canvas height="' + tileHeight + '" width="' + tileWidth + '"></canvas>').get(0);
        
        // draw the tile from the source
        tile.context.drawImage(tileSource, j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight, 0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);
        
        // add tile to array
        myTiles.push(tile);
    }
}
```

Note that the first parameter of the drawImage method can be either an Image object or a Canvas object.

Here is a good reference for using the canvas drawImage method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking several things so I'll try to address a few. It sounds like you're wanting to:

1. Define tiles, or regions of an image to
   be drawn
2. Define a map, a set of tiles in a
   specific order
3. Define a system to draw the map to a
   `<canvas>`

Just for kicks I developed something that does the three things mentioned above using JavaScript and `<canvas>`. [The source can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Maxamor/RkBdP/). *A word of caution: this code is pretty rough/raw and requires a modern browser to work (Chrome 6+, Opera 11, etc).*

**In the example:**

- Tiles are defined as a simple JavaScript object: `{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 0, h: 0 }`. Tiles are grouped into an object called `TileData`, which is just a grouping of tiles and their source image.
- A map is really just a big array of numbers which correspond to an index in a `TileData` object.
- Drawing the map is the responsibility of the `MapRenderer`, which looks up each tile's rectangle and draws it to a `<canvas>`.

This should get you started.